# FindPath not finding any path but FindShortestPath does?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pathfinding

Puzzled by this.
I have a directed graph, made by a set of hubs and leaves linking to them.

Vertices names are strings.

I tried to:

```
FindPath = [g, "insight", "perception", Infinity, All]
```

No result.

I tried to :

```
FindShortestPath[g, "insight", "perception"]
```

No result.

I thought, ok, maybe the graph must be undirected, if the algorithm for some reasons is following directed graphs:

```
FindShortestPath[UndirectedGraph@g, "insight", "perception"]
```

Result found:

```
{"insight", "personal purpose VS working motivation", "perception"}
```

But:

```
FindPath[UndirectedGraph@g, "insight", "perception", Infinity, All]
```

No Result.

Why FindPath fails to find at least the shortest path ?

How to get all paths between 2 nodes?
Below, the graph:

[image]

---

**Edited**

I share the Graph Data - I replaced the vertex names with numeric IDs for convenience. The Edge list is:

```
{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 19, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 19, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 21, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 22, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 22, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 23, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 23, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 27, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 28, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 31, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 32, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 32, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 34, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 35, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 39, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 40, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 45, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 45, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 47, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 48, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 47, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 48, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 47, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 48, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 47, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 48, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 47, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 48, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 49, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 49, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 49, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 50, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 52, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 46, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 28, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 53, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 54, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 55, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 57, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 57, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 58, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 59, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 58, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 59, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 60, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 60, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 61, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 61, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 62, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 62, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 64, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 65, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 66, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 67, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 66, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 67, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 68, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 69, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 68, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 69, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 70, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 71, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 72, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 73, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 74, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 75, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 75, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 77, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 78, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 79, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 80, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 80, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 81, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 81, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 82, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 82, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 84, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 85, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 86, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 87, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 87, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 88, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 89, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 89, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 90, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 91, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 90, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 91, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 92, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 93, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 94, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 93, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 94, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 95, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 96, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 97, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 97, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 97, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 98, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 98, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 99, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 100, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 101, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 102, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 103, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 23, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 104, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 104, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 105, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 105, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 106, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 107, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 106, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 107, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 108,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 111, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 111, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 111, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 112,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 113, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 114, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 113, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 114,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 115, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 116, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 115, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 116, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 117, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 117,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 118, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 118, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 119, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 120, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 119, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 120, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 121,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 121, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 122,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 123, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 36,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 123, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 36, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 124, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 125, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 126, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 127, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 128,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 127, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 128, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 129, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 129, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 130, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 130, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 130, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 132, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 132, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 133,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 133, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 133, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 134,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 135, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 135, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 136,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 136, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 137, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 38, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 40, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 139,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 141, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 142, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 142, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 143,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 144, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 145, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 146, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 59, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 147, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 148,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 151,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 151, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 152, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 152, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 153, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 154, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 155, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 156, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 157, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 158, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 66, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 67, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 66, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 67, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 159, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 68, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 69, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 68, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 69, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 160, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 161, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 162, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 161, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 162, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 163, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 163, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 164, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 164, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 165,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 165, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 166, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 138,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 167, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 168,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 168, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 169, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 169,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 170, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 171, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 172, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 173, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 174, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 175, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 172, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 173, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 174, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 175, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 158, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 158,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 80, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 80, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 176, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 176, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 177, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 177, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 178, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 178, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 179, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 180, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 180,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 181, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 181, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 182, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 183, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 184, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 185, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 186, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 187, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 187, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 188, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 189, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 190, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 191, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 105, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 105, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 192, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 192, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 115, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 194, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 115,
  36 \[DirectedEdge] 194, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 195, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 193,
  36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 195, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 196, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 196, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 132, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 132, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37,
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 198, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 198, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 199, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 199, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 104, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 104, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 106, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 107, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 106, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 107, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 12,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 200, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 201, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 201, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 110, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 202, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 136, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 203, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 204, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 205, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 206, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 207, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 208, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 113, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 114, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 113, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 114, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 211, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 212, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 212, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 132, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 192, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 192, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 115,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 116, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 115, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 116, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 118, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 118,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 115, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 194, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 115,
  36 \[DirectedEdge] 194, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 193, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 195, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 193,
  36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 195, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 119, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 120, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 119, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 120, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 121,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 121, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 122, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 213, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 213, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 19,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 19, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 123, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 36, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 123, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 36, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 214, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 214, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 127, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 128, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 127, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 128,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 127, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 128, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 52, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 35, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 215, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 216, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 39, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 217, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 218, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 218, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37,
  36 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 198, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 198, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 219, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 219, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 220, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 221, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 222, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 224, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 225, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 226, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 224, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 225, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 226, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 227, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 227, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 228, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 228, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 230, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 231, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 230, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 231, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 169, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 232, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 232, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 219, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 172, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 173, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 174, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 175, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 172, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 173,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 174, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 175, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 158,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 158, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 176, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 176, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 177, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 177, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 233, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 81, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 81, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 178, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 178,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 234,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 181, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 181, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 235, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 236, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 237, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 237, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 238, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 238, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 187, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 187, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 87,
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 87, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 89, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 89, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 90, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 91, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 90, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 91, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 239, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 240, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 241, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 97,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 97, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 242, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 242, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 98, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 98, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 243, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 243, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 244, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 245, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 246, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 108,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 108, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 109, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 247,
  25 \[DirectedEdge] 206, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 206, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 145, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 145, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 249, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 249, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 250, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 250, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 251, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 196, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 196, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 30, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 37, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 131, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 253, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 254, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 254, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 126, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 254, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 136, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 136, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 74, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 164, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 74, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42,
  43 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 49, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 49, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 256, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 257, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 258, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 139,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 142, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 142, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 259, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 57,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 57, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 56, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 139, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 150,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 148, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 149, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 150, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 151,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 151, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 140, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 152, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 140,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 152, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 61, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 61,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 260, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 260, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 254, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 197, 
 36 \[DirectedEdge] 199, 36 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 197,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 199, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 261, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 261, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 224,
  29 \[DirectedEdge] 225, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 226, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 224, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 225, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 226, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 227, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 227, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 163, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 163, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 164, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 164, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 262, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 262, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 263, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 264, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 265, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 266, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 267, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 268, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 269, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 270, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 271, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 272, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 272, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 273, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 273, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 274, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 275, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 274, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 275, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 201, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 201, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 276, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 111, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 111, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 277, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 117, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 117, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 278, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 278, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 135, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 135, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 216, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 35, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 35,
  43 \[DirectedEdge] 39, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 39, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 39,
  43 \[DirectedEdge] 180, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 279, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 280, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 3,
  76 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 260,
  43 \[DirectedEdge] 260, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 281, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 261, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 261, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 282, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 282, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 63,
  10 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 63, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 229, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 230, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 231, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 230, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 231, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 283, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 284, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 283, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 284, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 20, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 283, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 284, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 232, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 232, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 285, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 286, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 287, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 288, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 145, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 145, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 249, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 249, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 250, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 250, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 209, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 17,
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 213, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 213, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 290, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 22, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 22, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 23, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 23, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 278, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 278, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 33,
  18 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 33, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 223, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18,
  18 \[DirectedEdge] 291, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 18, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 18,
  9 \[DirectedEdge] 161, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 162, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 161, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 162, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 228, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 228, 
 9 \[DirectedEdge] 180, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 180, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 82, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 82, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 83, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 237, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 237, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 238, 18 \[DirectedEdge] 238, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 242, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 242, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 243, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 243, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 206, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 206, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 
 18 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 289, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 212, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 212, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 24, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 26, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 252, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 138, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 51, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 51,
  25 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 42, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 272, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 272, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 273, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 273, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 93, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 94, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 93, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 94, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 43, 
 25 \[DirectedEdge] 274, 25 \[DirectedEdge] 275, 
 29 \[DirectedEdge] 274, 29 \[DirectedEdge] 275, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 214, 
 10 \[DirectedEdge] 214, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 292, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 292, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 248, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 41, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 255, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 44, 43 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 
 43 \[DirectedEdge] 282, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 210, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 282, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 75, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 75, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 293, 76 \[DirectedEdge] 294, 
 76 \[DirectedEdge] 295}
```

Comment: Why don't you give the raw data g here?

Comment: Edited @A.Kato!

Comment: MMA version 13.1 Windows 10:  FindPath[g, 1, 44] gives: {{1, 43, 44}} and FindShortestPath[g, 1, 44] gives: {1, 44}. However, you chose the edges so that there are very few pathes. With undirected  edges we get:  {{1, 3, 9, 18, 29, 42, 43, 44}} and {1, 44}